# How to create custom url on Wordpress that call a specific function

Tags: wordpress

I would like to have a custom url on my Wordpress such as

http://mywordpress.com/index.php?act=doit

And this will call a specific function.

What is the best practice to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You need to give more info as to what you are trying to acheive, show code samples, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
add_action('init', 'init_url_custom_function');
function init_url_custom_function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^YOUR_CUSTOM_URL/?', 'index.php?is_custom_function=yes', 'top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%is_custom_function%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action( 'wp', 'check_url_custom_function' );
function check_url_custom_function() {
    global $is_custom_function;
    if (isset($is_custom_function) && $is_custom_function == "yes")
        custom_function();
}

function custom_function() {
    // do something
    die();
}
```

PS : you need to regenerate your permalink

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I am looking for.. Thank you: